# Como crear de forma dinámica en un formulario dos objetos de diferentes modelos

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Tengo estos modelos:

```
class Cientifico(models.Model):
    nombre_completo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nombre_abreviado = models.CharField(default="", max_length=200)
    unique_together  =  ( "nombre_completo" ,  "nombre_abreviado" )

class Coleccion(models.Model):
    colector_ppal = models.ForeignKey(Cientifico, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="principal")
    fecha = models.DateField()
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #colectores_secu = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    colectores_secu =models.ManyToManyField(Cientifico, through='Colectores', null=True, blank=True)

class Colectores(models.Model):
    coleccion =  models.ForeignKey(Coleccion, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    colector = models.ForeignKey(Cientifico, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    orden = models.IntegerField()
    unique_together  = ("coleccion", "colector")
```

Y deseo que en un formulario se pueda ingresar de forma dinámica varios colectores. Estoy usando `Formset`.

```
<!--colectores-->
            <table class="table">
            {{ colectoresFormset.management_form }}

            {% for form in colectoresFormset.forms %}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                {% endif %}
                <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row">
                   
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ form.colector }}</td>
                      <td>{{ form.orden }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/> 
    </form>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: 'add colector secundario',
        deleteText: 'remove',
        prefix: 'colectoresFormset_set'
    });
</script>
```

Pero haciendo esto así, me sale un `comboBox` con los científicos ya guardados, y yo deseo crear el científico al tiempo; es decir que en vez de salirme un `comboBox` me salgas dos text en los cuales pueda ingresar nombre completo y abreviatura y ademas el orden que hace parte del modelo Colector.

Muchas gracias. en estos momentos el formulario esta de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Enserio agradezco cualquier ayuda, he visto diferentes paginas, pero ninguna soluciona mi inquietud

Comment: Bienvenida Paola de preferencia que el código sea texto no imagenes

Comment: Ok, ya edite la pregunta. gracias

Comment: Si entiendo bien, quieres dentro del template poder crear un cienitifco nuevo y a la vez poder listar los cientificos existentes ?

Comment: no listar los existentes no, sino crear uno nuevo

Comment: Esto se hace con formset como bien has estado haciendo e en conjunto con AJAX, te recomiendo que revises bien la documentación sobre este tema, es bastante compleja para ponerte en la respuesta, porque estoy desde el móvil.

Comment: Revisa este enlace https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d espero te ayude, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Agradezco a todos los que me colaboraron, lo que yo buscaba unir en un formset tres modelos, y ese era mi inconveniente al final logre resolverlo de la siguiente aqui explico como para quien tambien pueda haber tenido mi duda:

A cada modelo le hize su form, solo que al formulario del modelo Colectores, no le relacione un modelo asi:

```
class ColectoresForm(forms.Form):

nombre = forms.CharField(
                max_length=100,
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control nombre-complete','placeholder': 'nombre completo '}),
                required=False)

abreviatura = forms.CharField(
                max_length=100,
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'abreviatura '}),
```

y la vista la hize como el ejemplo de esta pagina que recorren el formset y van guardando los objetos http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html